# How we create .htaccess for IIS ? Is it possible?

Tags: apache, iis, .htaccess

i don't know much about IIS, except it's a web server (just like apache) and mostly run for ASP. How we set library like moD_rewrtie and .htaccess in this kind of server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i know that in iis7 its possible to use a tool that make rules like mod rewrite

link :
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCAndTheNewIIS7RewriteModule.aspx